# How to get data attribute of event target in svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'd like to get the value of `data-url` in:

```
  {#each profiles as p}
    <div data-url={p.url} class="item" on:click={goToPage}>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 l4">
          <div class="a">
             <br />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 l8">
          <p>
            <strong>{p.fn} {p.ln}</strong><br />
            {p.ttl}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      {p.dsc}
       <hr />
    </div>
  {/each}
```

The function is:

```
  const goToPage = (e) => {
     var slug = e.target.querySelector("item").getAttribute("url");
    console.log("slug is:", slug);
    window.location.href = slug;
  };
```

However it does not work and I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute')
```

I have tried other things like

```
e.target.querySelector("item").getAttribute("data-url");
```

and

```
e.target.getAttribute("data-url");
```

but none of them worked.

Comment: Use attribute binding for it. https://svelte.dev/docs#bind_element_property

Comment: @SandipNirmal that is not applicable because the div is in a loop and there are several `someUrl`s here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest, most straightforward way is to simply pass the slug as an argument to the function instead:

```html
<div data-url={p.url} class="item" on:click={() => goToPage(p.url)}>
```

and the function becomes:

```js
const goToPage = (slug) => {
  console.log("slug is:", slug);
  window.location.href = slug;
};
```

Comment: Yes! this way data attribute `data-url={p.url} ` is not even needed and we are saved from intericacies of javascript event object. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

`e.target` references the thing you just clicked, you'll need to use `currentTarget` instead and you don't need to do `querySelector`

EG:

```
var slug = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-url");
```

I've done a basic example

```js
function goToPage(e){
  console.debug(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-url'));
}
```

```html
<div data-url="https://google.com" class="item" onClick="goToPage(event)">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 l4">
          <div class="a">
             <br />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 l8">
          <p>
            <strong>{p.fn} {p.ln}</strong><br />
            {p.ttl}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      {p.dsc}
       <hr />
    </div>
    
    <div data-url="https://google2.com" class="item" onClick="goToPage(event)">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 l4">
          <div class="a">
             <br />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 l8">
          <p>
            <strong>{p.fn} {p.ln}</strong><br />
            {p.ttl}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      {p.dsc}
       <hr />
    </div>
```

Comment: It works but is a hit-and-miss. Please refer to my edited question. I'd like the whole `div class="item" ` be anchored.

Comment: @Babr Not 100% clear on what you need, it would be helpful to see the whole code - if this is in a loop there's definitely a lot of missed context to what you're trying to achieve that would be useful in helping you

Comment: Right, I added the div in loop (a bit abbreviated). Please see the question. Basically I'd like the whole div to be clickable.

Comment: @Babr I've extended my answer and included a working snippet.

Comment: This does not work either. I get `slug is: null`  in the console.

Comment: It works in the snippet, what do you get when you `console.debug(e.currentTarget)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237591/discussion-between-babr-and-thebritisharecoming).